# Make 9v ups for router with TP4056 and MT3608

Tags: diodes, lithium-ion, lipo, ups

I am building 9v UPS for my wifi router using TP4056 lithium-ion charging module and MT3608 stepup converter. If USB power is available I want MT3608 to get power from USB (TP4056 Vin Pin) otherwise from battery (TP4056 Vout Pin). I don't have mosfet, So I am using diode Like this
[image]

IF USB power is avaliable does MT3608 pull current from higher voltage source (eg: from USB 5v rather then 4.2v from battery). Does this circuit will work?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this circuit will work?

9v*0.5A = 4.5W. Boost converters work on *power* (with losses), so if 4.5W are going to the router, then at least 4.5W (lets say 5W) must come from the source. 5v/5W = 1A. So 1A must be available from 5V to get 0.5A at 9v.

USB-C might be able to do this, but to get that much power from a USB-C port, it would have to be negotiated using a special chip. Standard USB ports can only deliver 0.1A.

> IF USB power is avaliable does MT3608 pull current from higher voltage source (eg: from USB 5v rather then 4.2v from battery)

The boost converter would totally be powered from whichever source was higher (after the voltage drop of the diodes.)

If attempted using a standard USB port, first it will try to run from USB, as that is higher than battery voltage. Exceeding 0.1A will cause the port to shut off, then the battery would power it. So it likely could be charged from the USB port, or operated when unplugged, but not operated while being charged.

Comment: Added problem: if the 18650 cell is flat, the charger will be trying to charge the cell from the USB at the same time as powering the router.  But it might work using a 2A USB charger that doesn't make any attempt to negotiate the current limit.

Comment: @rdtsc If I use USB 2amp wall changer to power TP4056 then It will work as expected ?

Comment: Yes that should work. The 2A wall charger could be as low as 3VDC, or as high as 9VDC to fall within the operating window of the [MT3608](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf).  Also consider the power dissipation of the diodes used. If they drop 0.7v at 1A, 0.7*1 = 0.7W (*2 and round up for robustness) = 2W rating and they will get warm.